# Ruby: When passing same parameters to multiple methods in inherited classes

Tags: ruby

What would be the proper Ruby way to simplify and avoid repetition of passing the same parameters to every single method inside each inherited class?

```
class Class0
  # some attributes and methods here
end

class Class1 < Class0

  def method1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    # do action #1 with arg1, arg2, arg3
  end

  def method2(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    # do action #2 with arg1, arg2, arg3
  end

end

class Class2 < Class0

  def method3(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    # do action #3 with arg1, arg2, arg3
  end

  def method4(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    # do action #4 with arg1, arg2, arg3
  end

end



obj1 = Class1.new
obj2 = Class2.new

obj1.method1(1, 2, 3)
obj1.method2(4, 5, 6)

obj2.method3(7, 8, 9)
obj2.method4(10, 11, 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply forward args without repeating them, you can use the splat operator `*`:

```
class Class0
  def method0(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    # Say this method something with args such as this:
    puts [arg1, arg2, arg3].join(", ")
  end
end

class Class1 < Class0
  def method0(*args)
    super(*args)
  end
end
```

Actually, just calling `super` from Class1 will forward the args, without you even needing to explicitly pass them:

```
class Class1 < Class0
  def method0(*args)
    super
  end
end
```

Strangely, `super()` will *not* pass the args. If you provide those empty parens or some other arguments to `super`, that will override the default behavior (which is to forward all the arguments).

The splat operator doesn't only work with `super`, by the way - you can use it anywhere that you define method parameters or pass arguments to a method. There is also a "double splat" operator `**` which is used for keyword args.

https://alexcastano.com/everything-about-ruby-splats/

Comment: Hi max - But, my Class0 wouldn't want each of redundant method0, method1, method2, etc., which would make the code even more repeating.
What I'm trying to find out is if there's a way to specify parameters only once in Class0 and any methods inside inherited Class1, Class2, Class3 could use those parameters coming from Class0.

Comment: @Steve i don't think you can. You would need to use splat

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the clear yes/no answer!

Comment: Yeah, I mean there are other workarounds, but if your question is "can i define a variable `params = arg1,arg2` such that `def foo(params)` makes the variables `arg1` and `arg2` available in the method", then no.

Comment: I want to pass arg1, arg2, arg3 to Class0 somewhere and to access arg1, arg2, arg3 in methods inside Class1 < Class0. It doesn't have to be with a variable of parameters. As long as I can get arg1, arg2, arg3 just one time inside Class0 and access them from Class1, Class2, etc., that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Steve it's really not clear. You need to show an actual reproducible example. And this question is already closed so might as well just make a new one.

Comment: Sure, max. I'll try it again soon. Thanks for your help!